# How do I plot the real part of an equation?

Tags: python, matplotlib, math

So basically I'm trying to plot this equation in python :

```
v = 0.78125 - exp(-5.05*t)*exp(-6773.05*i*t) + 0.22514*exp(-509.988*i*t)
```

But just the real part of it where the potential is on the y-axis and the time on the x-axis. How can this be achived ??

Comment: What do you mean by "plot the real part without the imaginary part"? What kind of plot do you want? What are the axes?

Comment: What is the range of t you want to plot?

Comment: From t = [0, 2]

Comment: The real part of the complex exponential is simply the cosine, why not use that?

Comment: I'll try that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real part of exp is cosine, but if you have a more complex equation where you need to extract the real part you can use v.real

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# use the built-in 'complex' function in Python, extract the real part
# complex(0,1) = 0 + 1.0i
def my_func(t):
    v = 0.78125 - np.exp(-5.05*t)*np.exp(complex(0,-6773.05)*t) + 0.22514*np.exp(complex(0,-509.988)*t)
    return v.real

# set whatever granularity you need
x_values = np.linspace(0, 2, 10000)

plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
plt.plot(x_values, my_func(x_values))
plt.xlabel('Time (seconds)')
plt.ylabel('Potential')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Derek ! Real life saver

Comment: Glad to be of help!